# The inverse type of Bernhard Leeb's solution for IMO‐1983–inequality

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, discriminant, research, triangle-inequality

> Given three side-lengths $a, b, c$ of a triangle. Prove that
> $$a^{2}b\left ( a- b \right )+ b^{2}c\left ( b- c \right )+ c^{2}a\left ( c- a \right )\geq 3\left ( a+ b- c \right )c\left ( a- b \right )\left ( b- c \right )$$
> Source: StackMath/@haidangel ft.@tthnew

I used discriminant to create this inequality, also $constant\!:\!=\!\!3$ is the best here. See_ [on.StackMath](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4048087/822157), that's what I'm doing research on, of course this inequality is a result. Not an answer. I think we use Bernhard Leeb's result to help a real lot
$$a^{2}b\left ( a- b \right )+ b^{2}c\left ( b- c \right )+ c^{2}a\left ( c- a \right ):= \left ( c+ a- b \right )\left ( c- a \right )^{2}b- \left ( b+ c- a \right )\left ( a- b \right )\left ( b- c \right )c$$

Comment: So is your question that you are looking for a proof of this inequality ?

Comment: Nice! Its quite strong atleast for the case when $a\ge b\ge c$ ,does buffalo way work,?

Comment: @haidangel How about $a = 12, b = 15, c = 17$?

Comment: By the way, if you change RHS into $24(a+b-c)(a-b)(b-c)c$ then it's true.

Comment: @RiverLi I try SOS, but no success, can you?

Comment: @tthnew My method: Using Ravi's substitutions, it suffices to prove that $$ \left( 6\,y+2\,z \right) {x}^{3}+ \left( -6\,{y}^{2}-2\,yz \right) {x
}^{2}+ \left( 2\,{y}^{3}-2\,{y}^{2}z-8\,y{z}^{2} \right) x+6\,{y}^{2}{
z}^{2}+2\,y{z}^{3}
 \ge 0. $$ Then prove that the discriminant of cubic (in $x$) is negative or zero.

Comment: @haidangel Ji Chen posted many interesting and difficult problems in AoPS. You are extracting these problems for us.

Comment: @haidangel I cannot access that link. But I find that Ji Chen was active in 2020 in that forum. However, the older posts are not there. See: https://bbs.cnool.net/other/ji23

Comment: @RiverLi It seems that he doesn't active there from 2021 to now.

Comment: @tthnew Yes, but it is about one year. Also, he is the moderator. Please try another way to contact him. Does Sir xzlbq know his address? You can search his paper to see if there is email address.

Comment: I guess I solved this problem a long time ago.  If you need the solution, I can find it from my old notebooks.

Comment: My solution was related this original inequality $a^2b(a-b)+b^2c(b-c)+c^2a(c-a)≥0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a comment but it's too long for a comment.

> Given $a, b, c$ be three side-lengths of a triangle. Prove that
> $$a^2b(a-b)+b^2c(b-c)+c^2a(c-a)\geqslant 3(a+b-c)(a-b)(b-c)c$$
> Source: By MSE/@tthnew

Some try to *proof:*  Since $a,b,c$ be three sid-lengths of a triangle, if $(a-b)(b-c)<0$ it's obvious.

So, we only need to consider this inequality when $(a-b)(b-c)\geq 0\to b\equiv \text{mid}\{a,b,c\}.$

But I can't prove this.

By the way if we change $3\to \frac{12}{5}=2.4,$ it's much easy to prove (for the weaker version).

Indeed, let $a=x+y,b=y+z,c=z+x$ and multiply our inequality with $x+y+z.$ The inequality becomes:
$$\frac{1}{20} \left( x-y \right)^2z^2 \left( 15x+31y \right) +\dfrac{1}{20}
 \left( 2x-y-z \right)^2y \left( 20x^2+19xy+46zx+37
z^2 \right) $$ $$+{\frac {21}{20}}
 \left( zx+y^2-2yz \right)^2x+\frac {17}{10} \left( x-z
 \right)^2y^2z+\frac {3}{20} \left( z+x-2y \right) ^2z
^2y$$
$$+\frac{2}{5} \left( x^2-yz \right)^2 \left( 2y+5
z \right) +\frac{1}{5} \left( y-z \right) ^{2}x^3\ge 0.$$

According to Mr. RiverLi's idea,
After let $a=x+y,b=y+z,c=z+x$ then $f(a,b,c)=f(x+y,y+z,z+x)\equiv f(x),$ and we only need to prove
$$\Delta_x=-16 y^2 (y-z)^4 (y+z) (3 y+z) \left(y^2-4 y z+27 z^2\right)\le 0,$$
which is clearly true. I'm still try to find another way.